# Lendo XLS em Java

Tags: java, xls

Possuo uma classe para ler um xls em java, e preciso saber como imprimir uma coluna ao lado da outra assim como na próprio xls. Até agora só consegui imprimir de forma corrida ou em linha unica.

OBS: Estou usando a biblioteca jxl.

Segue o código:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook( new File( "C:\\Users\\lm\\Desktop\\planilha.xls" ));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet( 0 );

        int rows = sheet.getRows();
        int columns = sheet.getColumns();


        for ( int i = 0; i < columns; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < rows; j++ )
            {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell( i , j );

                System.out.println( cell.getContents() );
            }

        }

        workbook.close();
```

Comment: Ou seja, você consegue ler todos os dados do XLS e só está com dificuldade em organizá-los no `System.out.println`?

Comment: Oi Victor ! Isso mesmo, pra que ele fique estruturado como se fosse a própria planilha.

Pensei em dentro do looping criar uma variável do tipo Cell para cada coluna e ir concatenando, mas são muitas colunas e eu gostaria de usar para mais de uma planilha este escopo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos dividir o problema em duas partes:

1. Transformar a planilha em uma matriz de `String`s.
2. Desenhar uma matriz de `String`s usando `System.out.println`.

Segue o código resultante:

```
public String[][] planilha(String nome)
    try (Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(nome))) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

        int rows = sheet.getRows();
        int columns = sheet.getColumns();
        String[][] matriz = new String[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                matriz[j][i] = cell.getContents();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static String padRight(String s, int tamanho) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tamanho);
    sb.append(s);
    for (int i = s.length(); i < tamanho; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public void imprimirMatriz(String[][] matriz) {

    // Primeiro calcula o tamanho de cada coluna.
    int colunas = matriz[0].length;
    int[] tamanhoColunas = new int[colunas];
    for (String[] linha : matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
            int t = linha[i].length();
            if (tamanhoColunas[i] < t) tamanhoColunas[i] = t;
        }
    }

    // Imprime a matriz.
    // Usa a função padRight para preencher os espaços corretamente.
    for (String[] linha : matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
            System.out.print(padRight(linha[i], tamanhos[i] + 1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void teste() {
    String[][] matriz = planilha("C:\\Users\\lm\\Desktop\\planilha.xls");
    imprimirMatriz(matriz);
}
```

Comment: Blz Victor, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado !